# Como construir um SELECT no SQLite?

Tags: java, android, sqlite

Sou novo no desenvolvimento Android, estou usando SQLite como banco. Preciso  fazer um SELECT, e retornar os valores de **três colunas da minha tabela**. Depois preciso setar os atributos do meu objeto com os valores de retorno desse **SELECT** .

1- Eu possuo um objeto chamado **ImageColor**, conforme código abaixo:

```
public class ColorImage {

    private int RedColor;
    private int GreenColor;
    private int BlueColor;
    private int Id;
    private String Nome;

   //Getters e Setters
}
```

2 - Minha tabela no banco está dessa forma:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu quero fazer um SELECT e retornar os valores do **RED**, **GREEN** e **BLUE**.

o meu método que faz o SELECT e retorna um objeto do tipo **ImageColor** e esse:

```
public ColorImage SelectedColor(String nome){

    ColorImage color = new ColorImage();

    String selectQuery = "SELECT red, green, blue FROM COLOR WHERE nome =" + nome;

    SQLiteDatabase banco = this.getWritableDatabase();

    Cursor cursor = banco.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

    color.setRedColor(cursor.getInt(0));
    color.setGreenColor(cursor.getInt(1));
    color.setBlueColor(cursor.getInt(2));

    return color;
}
```

Porém não está funcionando, não sei o que está errado.
Alguém sabe o que está errado?

Comment: Não retorna valor, não sei o que está errado.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A construção de comandos SQL dinâmicos com concatenação nem sempre produz o resultado esperado/válido.

Neste caso faltam as plicas. Elas são necessárias quando se usa uma *string* como valor. A forma correcta será assim:

```
String selectQuery = "SELECT red, green, blue FROM COLOR WHERE nome = " + "'" + nome + "'";
```

Para evitar este tipo de erros o indicado é usar *placeholders* para receber as partes dinâmicas e fornecer em separado os valores a usar. O método garantirá a correcta atribuição dos valores aos *placeholders*.

```
String selectQuery = "SELECT red, green, blue FROM COLOR WHERE nome = ?";
...
...
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, new String[] { nome });
```

Não esqueça de chamar `cursor.moveToFirst()` antes de utilizar o cursor.

```
public ColorImage SelectedColor(String nome){

    ColorImage color = new ColorImage();

    String selectQuery = "SELECT red, green, blue FROM COLOR WHERE nome = ?";

    SQLiteDatabase banco = this.getWritableDatabase();

    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, new String[] { nome });
    if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
        color.setRedColor(cursor.getInt(0));
        color.setGreenColor(cursor.getInt(1));
        color.setBlueColor(cursor.getInt(2));
    }
    cursor.close();

    return color;
}
```

Melhor ainda será usar um dos métodos [query()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#query(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[],%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[],%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String))

```
Cursor query(String table, 
             String[] columns, 
             String selection, 
             String[] selectionArgs, 
             String groupBy, 
             String having, 
             String orderBy)
```

No seu caso ficaria assim:

```
Cursor query("COLOR", 
             new String[]{"red", "green", "blue"}, 
             String "nome = ?", 
             new String[]{nome}, 
             null, 
             null, 
             null);
```

Comment: obrigado por sua resposta. Fiz exatamente como você disse, mas o App fecha por erro

Comment: E qual é o erro?

Comment: Consegui resolver o erro, mas ele sempre retorna zero para qualquer cor que eu procure. Ele não entra no **if( cursor.moveToFirst() )**

Comment: Se não entra no `if`é porque o cursor vem vazio. Verifique se existe algum registo que tenha um valor na coluna `nome` **exactamente igual** ao valor que está a passar ao método.